# Which table is primary key table?

Tags: database, foreign-keys, primary-key

For example, I have two tables.

- Name: Customer
- Primary key: idCustomer
- AnotherColumn: name
- Foreign key: idVendor

Another table:

- Name Vendor
- Primary Key: idVendor
- AnotherColumn: name

I want to create 1:n relation.

Which table is a primary key table and which is a foreign key table?

Comment: Both tables have primary keys. Only one seems to also have a foreign key. Your question doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Does a customer have many vendors or does a vendor have many customers?  IF vendor has many customers than customer has the FK to Vendor's PK.   But in my opinion you have a customer can have zero or many vendors and a vendor can have zero or many customers, thus, you need an associative table Vendor_Customers which contains the PK of vendor and customer (along with other necessary fields)

Comment: @Oded when I make relationship in VS I need to choose which table is a primary key table.

Comment: @xQbert Vendor has many customers.

Comment: This is the kind of thing you need to explain in your question. This is the first time VS has been mentioned. Other things you really should mention: Are you using Linq 2 SQL or EF (and what version)? And explain what difficulty you are having in determining which table is which.

Comment: Really? a customer can buy from only ONE vendor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you mean is which is the 1 and which is the n. The 1 would be vendor the n would be customer. you can have many customers to one vendor but only one vendor per customer.

Answer (score 0):

For your given schema, you're effectively creating a 1:N relationship between Vendor and Customer, i.e. 1 Vendor can have N customers. I hope that answers what you're looking for!

Answer (score 0):

> *Vendor has many customers*

In that case, the `Vendor` table will define a **primary key** of `idVendor` for the vendor, and the `Customer` table will have an `idVendor` foreign key column that references the `Vendor` table's primary key (`idVendor`).